# Why does my excel plus source in ssis outputting a fixed one date for all date columns?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2017

I have an excel file that I want to import using SSIS, I have done this process many more times without a problem with other excel files. however, this excel file has three spreadsheets on it. two of them works just fine importing correct data, BUT one of them is importing fixed data with `06-30-2019` for all date fields, and this not changing when it gets to table but it changed while it still at the source when I preview it, I see a fixed date already set up for date fields but other fields that are non-date fields are coming good.  the dates in the spread field of that sheet have different dates per row for that field/column. how is this happening? I am using SSIS 2017 and excel plus loads to table SQL 2017. how can I fix this?

in my excel sheet1

```
col1  datefield
1     01-08-2019
2     05-06-2019
3     06-12-2019
4     07-25-2019
```

in my excel source SSIS on preview show this below and that what it loads as well to table.

```
col1  datefield
1     06-30-2019
2     06-30-2019
3     06-30-2019
4     06-30-2019
```

Answer (score 0):

well, after I spent a great deal time, I have come to realize my excel file was in a shared file, which we can only access it VIA link/path given to me. instead, I was passing to my excel source the path from my local to that file(where I saved the file earlier), instead, I should have given the shared folder path, and happy to tell you all, the problem was solved.
However the Question Remains, why would Excel Plus Source do something like this and why choose a particular date 06/30/2019? I had that date on my file but not the only one and that date wasn't the first row in my data.